# How to set list data in list model at android?

Tags: java, android, model, structure

I custom my data model structure.

like below:

```
public class WeatherModel {

private String area = "";
private List<Interval> intervals;

public void setArea(String area)
{
    this.area = area;
}
public String setArea()
{
    return area;
}

public void setIntervals(List<Interval> intervals)
{
    this.intervals = intervals;
}
public List<Interval> getIntervals()
{
    return intervals;
}

public class Interval {
    private String startTime = "";
    private String endTime = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String maxT = "";
    private String minT = "";

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setMaxT(String maxT) {
        this.maxT = maxT;
    }

    public String getMaxT() {
        return maxT;
    }

    public void setMinT(String minT) {
        this.minT = minT;
    }

    public String getMixT() {
        return minT;
    }

}
}
```

if I have add some data to List through my  Main code.

I write below:

```
List<WeatherModel> weatherModelList = new ArrayList<WeatherModel>();

for( int areaIdx = 0; areaIdx< 10 ; areaIdx++ ) {
{
    WeatherModel weatherModel = new WeatherModel();
    weatherModel.setArea( myAreaData[areaIdx] );
      for( int partIdx = 0 ; partIdx< 7; partIdx++ )
      {

         weatherModel.getIntervals().set(partIdx).setDescription( myPartData[partIdx] );
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
         // here will show error 
         // set (int, interval) in List cannot appliedenter code here
      }
}
    weatherModelList.add(weatherModel);

}
```

It will show set (int, interval) in List cannot appliedenter code here.

but I don't know how to add many data to List < Interval > in this model.

Have anyone can teach me how to do?

thank you very much.

Comment: are you taking data from database or inserting it by yourself ?

Comment: no. if i have get some data(like xml ...). I parse these data , then I want to set to my model . but I don't know how to set every data to the List<Interval> .

Comment: you have to make adapter class where you will assign the data to the adapter and then it will be displayed in the list

Comment: My list not meaning android UI List. It's meaning java ArrayList data structure. please see my model code. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WeatherModel weatherModel = new WeatherModel();
weatherModel.setArea( myAreaData[areaIdx] );
  for( int partIdx = 0 ; partIdx< 7; partIdx++ )
  {
     Interval interval = new Interval();
     interval.setDescription( myPartData[partIdx] );
     weatherModel.getIntervals().add(interval);


  }
```

It would be helpful if you can share the XML as well

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
for (int areaIdx = 0; areaIdx < 10; areaIdx++){
    WeatherModel weatherModel = new WeatherModel();
    weatherModel.setArea("");
    List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<WeatherModel.Interval>();
    for (int partIdx = 0; partIdx < 10; partIdx++) {
         Interval interval = weatherModel.new Interval();
         interval.setStartTime("");
         interval.setEndTime("");
         interval.setDescription("");
         interval.setMaxT("");
         interval.setMinT("");
         intervals.add(interval);
    }
    weatherModelList.add(weatherModel);
}
```